# MySql exclusion query

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
JOB_ID  | Email        | Type       | Date      
_____________________________________
28319   | mike@aol.com | Service    | 11-24-2016
_____________________________________ 
28412   | mike@aol.com | Rotation   | 11-24-2016
_____________________________________
38123   | andy@aol.com | Service    | 11-24-2016
_____________________________________
28199   | roger@aol.com| Service    | 11-24-2016
```

What would be the query i would run to return those who have a service scheduled but do not have a rotation on a specific date.

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT j.Job_ID,j.Email,j.Type,j.Date
from Jobs j 
join
     Jobs  j2
     on j.Email = j2.Customer_Email
where j2.JOB_ID NOT IN (select j.JOB_ID
                  from Jobs j
                  where j.Type = 'Rotation'
                 )     AND j.Date = '11-24-2016';
```

So my query would return andy and roger.

Comment: As an aside, be sure to store dates using an appropriate data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you, no need for joins here:

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE Date = '11-24-2016' AND Type = 'Service' AND 
Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM Jobs WHERE Date = '11-24-2016' AND 
Type = 'Rotation');
```

Comment: @Strawberry there is absolutely nothing wrong with JOINs